# Can't use kotlin-multipatform project

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I try to create my first Kotlin multiplatform project in Intellij Idea Community 2019.2.3.

Was used default IDE project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUNmx.png)

But even default project build with exception like this [ko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyb7y.png)

my versions:
koltin 1.3.50
gradle:       4.4.1
Groovy:       2.4.16

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the Gradle version. The `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin that is used to build multiplatform projects is only compatible with Gradle versions 4.7 and above, as [said in the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#gradle-plugin).

Consider using an up-to-date Gradle version (Gradle 5.6.2 at the moment, check for updates [here](https://gradle.org/releases/)), which will also likely give better performance and other benefits.

To update the version, modify `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project, replacing the `distributionUrl` property. For instance, the line could look like:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip
```

Or, if you are not using a Gradle wrapper, just call `gradle` from a newer version distribution.