# Cannot update kotlin to v1.3.50 for multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using kotlin `1.3.41` for my multiplatform project (included `ios`, `jvm`, `js`) and everything is ok. Now I'm trying to update to the latest version 1.3.50 but get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlinNpmInstall'.
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.npm.KotlinNpmResolutionManager$ResolutionState$Installed cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.npm.KotlinNpmResolutionManager$ResolutionState$Configuring
```

I have tried to search everywhere (github, kotlin issue tracker) but got nothing. Does anyone know what causes this error? Thanks.

Part of my configuration:

> Root project configuration

```
buildscript {
  apply from: "buildsystem/dependencies.gradle"

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/" }
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.android
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.androidNavigation
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.node
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.kotlin
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.kotlinSerialization
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.kotlinAtomicfun
    classpath deps.gradlePlugins.dokka
  }
}
```

> Multiplatform module configuration

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'

apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

kotlin {
  targets {
    jvm("jvm")
    js("js") {
      nodejs {}
    }
    iosArm64("ios64")
    iosX64("iosSim")
    configure([ios64, iosSim]) {
      binaries.framework {
        baseName = "LIB"
      }
    }
  }

  sourceSets {
    def commonDependencies = rootProject.ext.deps.common
    commonMain {
      dependencies {
        implementation commonDependencies.kotlin
        implementation commonDependencies.kotlinCoroutines
      }
    }
    commonTest {
      dependencies {
        implementation commonDependencies.kotlinTest
        implementation commonDependencies.kotlinTestAnnotations
        implementation commonDependencies.mockk
      }
    }

    def jvmDependencies = rootProject.ext.deps.jvm
    jvmMain {
      dependencies {
        implementation jvmDependencies.kotlin
        implementation jvmDependencies.kotlinCoroutines
      }
    }
    jvmTest {
      dependencies {
        implementation jvmDependencies.kotlinTest
        implementation jvmDependencies.kotlinTestJunit
        implementation jvmDependencies.kotlinCoroutinesTest
        implementation jvmDependencies.mockk
      }
    }

    def jsDependencies = rootProject.ext.deps.js
    jsMain {
      dependencies {
        implementation jsDependencies.kotlin
        implementation jsDependencies.kotlinCoroutines
        // npm
        implementation npm("uuid", "^3.3.2")
      }
    }
    jsTest {
      dependsOn jsMain
      dependsOn commonMain
      dependencies {
        implementation jsDependencies.kotlinTest
      }
    }

    def iosDependencies = rootProject.ext.deps.ios
    iosMain {
      dependencies {
        implementation iosDependencies.kotlinCoroutines
      }
    }

    ios64Main {
      dependsOn iosMain
    }

    iosSimMain {
      dependsOn iosMain
    }
  }
}
// other configuration
```

Comment: If this relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166247/cant-use-kotlin-multipatform-project/58167100#58167100  ?

Comment: @lotor I don't think so, different error

Comment: Please report this to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Did you find solution to this....I'm only seeing it within Android Studio....works on command line

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I used IntelliJ instead, got no solution with AS

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the issue is in Android Studio.

When I run the official [KotlinJS react app tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/01_Introduction) on IntelliJ, the app works. But on AS, I get the above error when executing any Gradle task dependent on npm.

Until the issue is resolved, I recommend using the Community version of IntelliJ. You can download it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac)